# Vue3, Vite and Pre compiled templates to avoid 'unsafe-eval'

Tags: vuejs3, vite, vue-loader

Is there a way to pre compile Vue3 templates for client side rendering using Vite to avoid 'unsafe-eval' errors? Seems like Vue-Loader allowed template pre compilation but I am not finding the same option on Vite. Am I missing something?